# My Android App crashes and gives illigale access exception, i've tried to implement a tcp service to communicate with my server

Tags: java, android, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to write a service to communicate with a tcp server on www.herbrich.org:2147

But my app keep on crashing every time i run it. Here is my full code from the service class.

`ServiceClass`:

```
package org.herbrich.katana;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 16.04.2015.
 */
public class LocalService extends Service{
    LocalService()
    {
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    //JenniferHerbrich Network Ansi Declares
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT;
    private static final String SERVER_IP;

    static {
        SERVER_IP = "10.141.0.151";
        SERVERPORT = 2147;

    }

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public method
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
        return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
    public String communicateWithEvelin(String EvelinValue)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader input;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(EvelinValue);
            out.flush();
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
            return input.readLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I think i've some problem with the multithreading call inside the constructor method. The debug console gives me  `illegalAccessExceptions`..

LogCat:

```
04-15 18:52:08.632    9182-9182/org.herbrich.katana E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service org.herbrich.katana.LocalService: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2599)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2596)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 18:52:08.640    9182-9197/org.herbrich.katana E/TCP Client﹕ C: Connecting...
```

Comment: every question that says "crash" should have a StackTrace and point showing what is the exactly line number that this crash happens, without it, nobody will help you. Please edit your question.

Comment: thanks you for reply,

Can you tell me what you need, i am working with android studio. How i can get the StackTrace?

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: the moment it crashes, the android device post a kind of "crash report" in the LogCat. AndroidStudio have a `Android` window with a LogCat tab. There you can see all the messages posted by the system and if you filter errors and in your application you should have all that important debug information.

Comment: 8773-8773/org.herbrich.katana E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service org.herbrich.katana.LocalService: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed

Comment: this is the first error

Comment: It would be good if you can post the whole crash log.

Comment: I've tryed but it's to long for a comment on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Attach the logcat along with your question.

Comment: edit your question and add logcat as an image

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2599)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)

Comment: so, it's done. Tell me if you need more.

Comment: Is your LocalService class mentioned in the manifest? Did you request INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: yes and yes, thats the first what i do ater creating the service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `ClientThread` class must be public, and has a public zero-argument constructor, and that the constructor chains to the `superclass'` constructor.

Comment: Ok, i've declared the ClientThreadh Class as public an add a emtty constructor that calls super();